# Getting variable name passed in tagged templating

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to retrieve the **name of the variables** inside a tagged Template function. To be more clear, this is the code:

```
let date = "2018"; //can be undefined
let description = "my description"; //can be undefined
let age; //can be undefined, and it is here
    function processString(parts) {
        var res = parts[0];
        for (var i=1; i<parts.length; i++) {
            if (arguments[i]) res += /*** arguments[i] is the value, I want to append the variable name too***/ arguments[i];
            res += parts[i];
        }
        return res;
    }
    console.log(processString`
    ${date}
    ${description}
    ${age}
    `);
```

This is the result

```
2018
my description
20
```

I want this

```
date: 2018
description: my description
age: 20
```

**EDIT:** 
The whole purpose is to generate a list of "optional" rows (the original code is more complex of course, actually it generates a SQL-like query), but if the variable arguments[i] is defined I want to append to the resulting string "variable_name: variable_value" please note I edited the function `processString`.
**If there is any solution, I would prefer to edit `processString` and keep clean the `console.log`**

Comment: Yes it is possible, but every way i can think of requires some very hacky usage of `with` and Proxies, so i guess it might be better to just pass in the name `${"date"}` and then access its value as `window[arguments[i]]` or you just hardcode it `date: ${date}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend on Angelas' answer, you could pass in an object literal, as:

```
{name}
```

is the same as

```
{"name" : name}
```

So you can access both the name and the values. The template would look like:

```
function template(str, ...args) {
  let result = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
    result += str[i];
    result += Object.entries(args[i])[0].join(" : ");
  }
  result += str[i];
  return result;
}
```

So that you can do:

```
template`
  1 - ${{date}}
  2 - ${{description}}
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the desired result by using object destructuring.

```
  const getVarName = (nameObj) => {
    for(let name in nameObj) {
      return name;
    }
  }

  let date = "2018";
  let description = "my description";
  let age = 20;
    function processString(parts) {
      var res = parts[0];
      for (var i=1; i<parts.length; i++) {
        res += /*** arguments[i] is the value, I want to append the variable name too***/ arguments[i];
        res += parts[i];
      }

      return res;
  }
    console.log(processString`
     -1 ${getVarName({date})} ${date}
     -2 ${getVarName({description})} ${description}
     -3 ${getVarName({age})} ${age}
    `);
```

Comment: This is actually a very clever idea. I would change it to `${{name}}` and then let the template do its job.

Comment: Please read the edit, the variables actually can be undefined (each row is optional)